# Vintage book cover showing humanoid astronauts in upper body EVA suits but a "pod" or "monopant" lower half?

Tags: short-stories, novel, art, cover-art, image-identification

In comments under the Space SE question [Why do EVA suits have legs?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57752/12102) the OP clarifies that for a humanoid astronaut performing extravehicular activities their suit may not need individual legs but instead there could be a single "leg" or a hard shell or pod.

This brings (vaguely) to mind some old SciFi cover art with humanoid astronauts wearing exactly this; a hard shell or "pod" lower half and more of a "suit" like upper half with legs, either doing work or jetting a short distance from one object to the next as part of some activity.

Is this enough of a description to track this down?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is the type of suit described in "[Islands in the Sky](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11176)", a novel by Arthur C. Clarke. Published in 1952, I guess this counts as "vintage" sci-fi. Similarly to the remarks given in the question, Clarke wrote:

> To most people, the word "space suit" conjures up a picture of
> something like a diving dress, in which a man can walk and use his
> arms. Such suits are, of course, used on places like the moon. But on
> a space station, where there's no gravity, your legs aren't much use
> anyway, because outside you have to blow yourself round with tiny
> rocket units.

and so the people on the space station used a design which did not have legs:

> For this reason, the lower part of the suit was simply a rigid
> cylinder. When I climbed inside it, I found that I could use my feet
> only to work some control pedals, which I was careful not to touch.
> There was a little seat, and a transparent dome covering the top of
> the cylinder gave me good visibility. I could use my hands and arms.

The cover art shows the features clearly.

[image: Cover of "Islands in the Sky" showing a space station and two men in spacesuits]

Comment: Excellent, I believe this is exactly what I was remembering, description/narration and all. Searching further I just found https://twitter.com/pulplibrarian/status/906201906741215233

Comment: I found the same image linked from a nasaspaceflight.com forum thread on [legless spacesuits](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=33895.0), so it's a bit of a canonical example of the idea.

Comment: @DavidW I can't think of a more canonical SF author! I've even referenced Clarke in Math SE [What are "3D Burning Ship fractals"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2322660/284619)